# How to log changes made by users of a system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, logging

I have a system (c#/asp.net/sqlserver) where users can log in and manage products of a store. I need to log in the database every change made by users on the products. Ex:

```
Product A
Inserted by USER1 on 10/03/2013 10:00
Description changed to "Product AA" by USER2 on on 10/03/2013 12:00
```

Actually I have a PRODUCT_LOG table that is similar to the PRODUCT table and every time some record on PRODUCT is changed, the record is inserted on PRODUCT_LOG. Proceeding this way, I can return an "readable" log to the system's administrators (like above).

However, I create a big problem on maintaining FK on logs, after some time of logging, many registers won't be deleted from system because they're referenced on log tables as FKs. :(

I would ask if there's another option or some better method to generate this type of logs.
If you know the name of the methods, please, tell me so I can Google for it.

Comment: this is called auditing.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the FK constraints, then it'll work. What you're wanting are referred to as "Audit tables" and they don't need referential-integrity because they're meant to be immutable-once-written and everlasting, so it doesn't make sense to include them in JOINs with other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Referential integrity (Foreign Keys vanishing) is one of the problems with this sort of log retained by a database.  But you can also add tables to your schema where you move "deleted" rows from your FK tables.  Then you compute joins on the log table using a union of the 'live' FK tables and the 'deleted' FK tables.  Bam@! no missing FK's.

Or you could denormalize the data in you log files (expand the FK linked fields to data columns in your log file).  Yes, that takes more room, but saves query time and records the information as it appeared when the event occured.

Comment: This will also make auditing actually possible, what if you are interested in log entry #5, while someone changed the same product in log entry #1958? You will have a hard time trying to trace back the product to it's exact state if you allow the PRODUCT table to be modified and link your PRODUCT_LOG table to it.